# Creating Entity Frame work via model first in visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, t-sql, database-design, entity-framework-5

I am starting from scratch and have never done database creation through model first.

I have a several tables so far.

```
**Departments**
departmentID INT PK
name string
description string
owner string

Navigation Properties -> Functions (FK on departmentID)

**Functions**
functionID int PK
departmentID int FK
name string
description string
owner string

Navigation Properties -> Departments (FK on depaertmentID)
```

I am adding a new table called `Process`.

```
**Process**
proceddID int PK
name string
description string
owner string
```

Do I create an association from `Process` to `Functions` only?  If I do create the association from `Process` to `Functions` will it chain like this?

Departments.Functions.Process?

Or will I need to create an association from `Process` to `Functions` AND to `Departments`?

If this info is needed.

Departments can have many functions

Functions must be attached to a department but can have many Processes.

Processes must be attached to a function, but can have many Procedures.

*Visual Studio 2010
SQL Server 2008
Entity Framework 5.0*

Comment: So is functions-processes many to many? Or is Processes sef-referencing in a `1` (Process) - `n` (Processes) relationship? (The word "procedures" is a bit confusing).

Comment: Each function may have many processes.  A process will always be attacked to a function. @GertArnold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got `Departments ⎯ᗕ Functions ⎯ᗕ Processes`.

It is enough to have a one-to-many association between `Function` and `Process` (`Process` has a foreign key to `Function`). The inverse relationship (`Function.Process`) is not necessary, but it depends on your business logic whether you need it or not.

An association between Process and Department is redundant and, thus, not recommended.

To get Processes starting from Departments you can do:

```cs
from d in context.Departments
from f in d.Functions
from p in f.Processes
select ....
```

or

```cs
context.Departments
       .SelectMany(d => d.Functions)
       .SelectMany(f => f.Processes)
       .Select(...)
```